# Getting 404 error while configuring REST API using RestClient in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

When I try to initiate oauth for getting oauth tokens with callback in my localhost, it throws 404 page not found error. I configured consumer key and secret and with oAuth 1.0 and using GET method.

URL I'm using for getting oauth tokens is below:
http://your-magento-path/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=http://example.com

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error 404 always occurs if

1. there is difference in file naming or files name does not match
2. calling from somewhere can't find the proper path to controller

In simple this occurs when it can't find requested url or file

I think in your case oauth tokens with callback to your localhost is unable to find the requested URL in you localhost

kindly verify your URL on localhost first either it is working or not and then use that URL to call

accept if helps

Comment: Sure, I'll check it.